# Wish to terminate main.exe after execute DLL (C++)

Tags: c++, dll, windows-ce

I run my main.exe on a mobile device which executes my test.dll. Now after the dll has startet I need to wm_destroy the main.exe for exchange while the dll is still running. I'm pretty new to this field and I see it's against all logic. But maybe there is a way to change the main.exe while dll is running.

Thx in advance!

Answer (score 0):

When a DLL is loaded it's linked into the address space of the main executable. It doesn't and isn't supposed to exist independently. DLLs don't "run"/"execute" independently.

What you want to do is not what DLLs for. You probably want to spawn a new, independent process, and from there send the WM_DESTROY to the parent process.

Answer (score 0):

What purpose this can even serve? If dll is running by itself, it's an .exe and should have own WinMain, not just DllMain. Actually they have same format, both .dll and .exe are PEXE files and can have exports. It's a bit tricky to get address of exported function from running module that isn't child process, but it's how certain profiler tools work, including VS analyzer.

In Windows there is utility which sole purpose is to run a dll, rundll32, which you can spawn as child process, but it requires elevated rights.